# Change editor tab with a hotkey?

Tags: interface, shortcut

Are there hotkeys for changing between the tabs in the 3D view Toolshelf (Tool, Create, Relations, etc), or is it possible to create them?

Comment: You could scroll them with `LMB` however cursor should be over the tabs. If you need particular rollout in every tab you could `Shift` click its name.

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think that is currently possible, at least not without some scripting involved. But then again you seem to want to streamline or speedup your workflow, if you are going to bother creating or memorizing hotkeys for tabs why not got the full length do it directly for the tools you will be using instead. They most likely already exist and will probably be much faster that tab switching and pressing another button.

Comment: I agree with the guys above. Pin all of the tabs (Shift+LMB, while hovering the cursor over the panel's name) and make a long list. Pinning tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1ik0rlJuK4